# The "with" statement - accessing "entered" objects in lower scopes (without explicitly passing down information through arguments)

Tags: python

I'm having a hard time finding the correct library or a way to view the context as needed. I've looked here, but no dice so far: https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html.

I would want to:

1. Check if an instance of MyObj is entered
2. If it's entered, access it's properties

```
class MyObj:
    def __init__(self):
        self.prop = "some property"
        print("init MyObj")

    def __enter__(self):
        print("enter MyObj")

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        print("exit MyObj")


def lower_func(text):
    if "This func is called from a block where an instance of MyObj is entered":
        #  Print MyObj.prop here
        pass
    print(text)


def higher_func():
    with MyObj():
        lower_func("Printing this while MyObj is entered!")

    lower_func("Printing this while MyObj is exited!")
```

Is there a way to do that?

Currently, higher_func() is outputting:

```
init MyObj
enter MyObj
Printing this while MyObj is entered!
exit MyObj
Printing this while MyObj is exited!
```

What I want it to output:

```
init MyObj
enter MyObj
some property
Printing this while MyObj is entered!
exit MyObj
Printing this while MyObj is exited!
```

The goal is to implement this in a logging type of a function where it logs some information when it's available. Also to make the implementation as straight forward as possible. Basically it should work like a custom scope, where if MyObj is in the "entered" state, the lower-level functions would behave differently.

Comment: See point 5. [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement). You can return an object from `__enter__`  that is assigned to the `as` target of `with`.

Comment: @progmatico But if I do `with MyObj() as my_obj` in higher_func(), that my_obj variable is out of scope for lower_func. That's the thing I'm trying to work around.

Comment: Just pass it as an additional arg to `lower_func`.

Comment: That's what I'd do if it was that simple. But that's just an example. Let's say I want to incorporate that into a logging function which can reside in any function in any scope and I don't want to continuously add extra arguments to every log line.

Comment: Oh, I see.... This is not easy to deduce from the answer. I think you should add to the title "without passing arguments down the calling chain" or something similar.

Comment: For curiosity only, the Tcl language has `upvar`and `uplevel` to allow the access to vars or evaluation of commands (Tcl statements) in different scopes of the scope chain.

Comment: This has the potential to both solve some problems and exponentially grow the usual "global var sharing" problem. In your answer below I think this is addressed in the contextvars context copy capability.

Comment: Totally agree, the description isn't quite universally understandable as I didn't know the right words for describing it. I updated the title. To add - the `context_var` object has to be the same object instance in every call to it, otherwise it treats it as another var. Initially I tried to use a static global var name and address it like that, but there's no capability for it (yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I was looking for is exactly what is described in [PEP 555](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0555/), but unfortunately the proposal was withdrawn and never implemented in that state.

What I did find functionally similar was [PEP 567](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0567/) / [contextvars](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html) and that solves my problem. In my use case, I'd just have to make the ContextVar global.

A quick demonstration, which shows that the custom context is also thread-safe. They get evaluated in one order, and called in another. `my_vars`'s value is never explicitly handed down to `lower_func`:

```
import contextvars
import threading
import random
import time

print_lock = threading.Lock()
my_vars = contextvars.ContextVar("my_vars", default={})


def lower_func(expected_str, wait_time):
    context = contextvars.copy_context()

    # Checks if var exists in context and has a non-empty value
    if my_vars in context and context[my_vars]:
        with print_lock:
            print(f"{expected_str}, "
                  f"Actual: "
                  f"a={context[my_vars]['a']}, "
                  f"b={context[my_vars]['b']}, "
                  f"waited {wait_time}s")


def worker():
    wait_time, a, b = random.randint(0, 9), random.randint(0, 9), random.randint(0, 9)
    expected_str = f"Expected: a={a}, b={b}"  # Some values to cross-check against

    token = my_vars.set({"a": a, "b": b})
    time.sleep(wait_time)
    lower_func(expected_str, wait_time)
    my_vars.reset(token)


def higher_func():
    for _ in range(10):
        threading.Thread(target=worker).start()
```

Output example:

```
Expected: a=5, b=2, Actual: a=5, b=2, waited 0s
Expected: a=5, b=5, Actual: a=5, b=5, waited 0s
Expected: a=6, b=7, Actual: a=6, b=7, waited 1s
Expected: a=7, b=3, Actual: a=7, b=3, waited 4s
Expected: a=1, b=1, Actual: a=1, b=1, waited 5s
Expected: a=5, b=2, Actual: a=5, b=2, waited 6s
Expected: a=4, b=8, Actual: a=4, b=8, waited 6s
Expected: a=2, b=9, Actual: a=2, b=9, waited 7s
Expected: a=6, b=0, Actual: a=6, b=0, waited 8s
Expected: a=3, b=6, Actual: a=3, b=6, waited 9s
```